# Excel - Substitute a Cell-Based Formula to the Actual Cell Values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to convert a cell-based formula so the cells in the formula are substituted to their actual values? Without auto-completing?

Here's an example, lets just say the formula is:

```
=A1+A2+B6
```

And...

```
A1=2, A2=5 and B6=21.
```

How can I turn my formula from this..

```
=A1+A2+B6
```

...to this...

```
=2+5+21
```

...without doing it manually? I believe there is a way.

Thank you.

Comment: [regex] the R1C1 cell addresses out of the [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for simple situations where all of the formula references are on the same sheet. I use the `DirectPrecedents` range, but that limits you to precedent cells on the same sheet.

In my example I have, this in `Sheet1`

```
  |                       A                     |
--+---------------------------------------------+
1 |  2                                          |
2 |  4                                          |
3 |  6                                          |
4 | =Sheet1!A3+(A1^Sheet1!A1)+Sheet1!A2/(A3+A2) |
5 | =SUM(A1,A2,A3)/COUNT(A1,A2,A3)              |
```

Note the mix of cell references that include a cell with a named sheet prefix.

And I use this VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
  PrintResolvedFormula Range("A4")
  PrintResolvedFormula Range("A5")
End Sub

Sub PrintResolvedFormula(rng As Range)

  If rng.HasFormula Then

    Dim formula As String
    formula = rng.FormulaR1C1

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.DirectPrecedents.Cells
      formula = Replace(formula, cel.Worksheet.Name & "!", vbNullString)
      formula = Replace(formula, cel.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, False, rng), cel.Text)
    Next cel

    Debug.Print formula

  Else

    Debug.Print rng.Value

  End If

End Sub
```

And get this output:

```
=6+(2^2)+4/(6+4)
=SUM(2,4,6)/COUNT(2,4,6)
```

Note that is resolves the cell references to values, but it does not resolve the functions to values. To resolve the individual functions you'd to break out the function string and use `Application.Evaluate`.